# ios-webkit-debug-proxy blank devtools

Tags: ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using ios-webkit-debug-proxy on Linux to try and debug an iOS Safari host using chrome.

The debug proxy runs and gives

```
Listing devices on :9221
Connected :9222 to Will's iPhone (8a48ac86edd4f299xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

The page localhost:9222

[image: lh:9222]

Opening the devtools though gives a whole lot of blank. Clicking on lots of things yields little.

[image: devtools]

Can someone with experience with these things give me a nudge? Cheers

Comment: Damn I have the exact same problem :(

Comment: Sorry! Didn't manage to find a solution, its on the backlog.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will keep you posted if I find a solution. cheers

Answer (score 1):

What Chrome version are you using? This might happen as this feature is broken since chrome 38. Try downloading Chromium 37 to solve the issue.

Checkout this Bug Report for details:

https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/issues/78

Old binaries can be obtained from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxportableapps/files/Chromium/

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this procedure from **Ryan Ewen**](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter/issues/138#issuecomment-531406375):

> Comprehensive instructions for Windows:
>
> - Get files from https://github.com/fishbone1/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter
> - Install iTunes (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/itunes/9pb2mz1zmb1s)
> - Install scoop (https://scoop.sh)
> - `scoop install nodejs nvm`
> - `scoop bucket add extras`
> - `scoop install ios-webkit-debug-proxy`
> - `nvm install 11.15.0` (version 12 doesn't work for the final couple of steps)
> - `nvm use 11.15.0` (might have to reopen PowerShell after this, it'll tell you)
> - `npm install -g vs-libimobile` cd to your download of remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter
> - `npm install`
> - `npm start`
> - Continue onto Step 3 [from the readme](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you installed latest `ios_webkit_debug_proxy`:

```
brew install ios-webkit-debug-proxy
```

and then launch `ios_webkit_debug_proxy`using command:

```
ios_webkit_debug_proxy -f chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html
```

BTW you must use developer's certificate to build the app!

Answer (score 0):

Install the adapter with :
*npm install remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter -g*

Then, run *remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter --port=9000*